# Overlapping times issue with 'findmeetingtimes' call in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

When attempting to complete a `findmeetingtimes` call with the Microsoft Graph API (as seen here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findmeetingtimes), I am experiencing an issue where asynchronously looping and completing the call is returning a `500 error` only when two meetings are scheduled in the exact same time slot (i.e. two meetings are scheduled at exactly 4:30PM - 5:00PM. The exact error message in the error object that is returned is:

> "Invalid value for arg:Overlaps are not supported within TimeSlots,
>   value:{"start":2017-05-10T20:00:00Z,"min":30} ↵Parameter name:
>   Overlaps are not supported within TimeSlots"

Does anyone have any suggestions for a fix/work around for this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the request you're making? You're saying that to reproduce this you just have two meetings on the user's calendar at the same time?

Comment: Hi @JasonJohnston, this is the JSON body that is being sent with the request.
`{
 "IsOrganizerOptional":true,
 "MinimumAttendeePercentage":0,
 "ReturnSuggestionReasons":true,
 "MaxCandidates":100,
 "Attendees":[
   {
    "Type":"Optional",
    "EmailAddress":
    {
      "Name":"MyEmail",
      "Address":"myemail@email.com"
    }
}],
"TimeConstraint":
{
  "Timeslots": [
    {"Start": {"DateTime":"2017-05-12T16:30:00.000Z","TimeZone":"GMT Standard Time"},
    "End":{"DateTime":"2017-05-12T17:00:00.000Z","TimeZone":"GMT Standard Time"}}]},"MeetingDuration":"PT30M"}`

Comment: The call to `findmeetingtimes` is being done asynchronously in a loop for the available meeting time slots in the day. The error that is returned is a 500 error that appears to be when there are two meetings with the exact same time slot scheduled. The error seems to disappear when one of the meetings has a different status ('Busy' vs 'Free')

Comment: Ok. I've reported to Graph and Outlook teams and they're investigating.

Comment: Hey @JasonJohnston, this issue appears to be fixed! Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed. No one told me :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in our API. We've deployed a fix that should clear this up.